# uncommenting specific code in a larger file

Tags: text-processing

I have these lines of code in my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file in Ubuntu 15.
How can I uncomment only those lines from the command line, without without messing up any other comments in the file?

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Remember that there are other lines of code in this file that I don't want to mess up and that this should be done automatically by a bash script.

Comment: Why automatic? Use `vi` :-)

Comment: How can the script know which comments are real comments and which are commented code?

Comment: What chaos has mentioned severely limits the automation simplicity. You'll have to write lexical parser for bash that makes sense of semantics in your file (excluding the #) and leave the # untouched on lines where it does NOT make sense to the parser. A simpler solution is what Ned64 suggested. Use `vi` -> 1) Find the lines to be uncommented 2) `Esc` followed by `Ctrl + V' to enter visual block mode 3) Select the '#'s by pressing `h` or `k` 4) 'd' to delete followed by `Esc` and Voila! Vim experts could probably do this in 1  key ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In fact what is asked it a very wrong way to do multiprofiles bashrc. 
You should just have several different .bashrc files like .bashrc_1, .bashrc_rc2, where you define your different need from the basic .bashrc file and source them when needed.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a definitive answer without seeing the entire file. If there is only one instance of `if ! shopt -oq posix;` and ` you can use that to delimit the relevant section:

```
perl -i -pe '$i++ if /^#if ! shopt -oq posix;/; s/^#// if $i==1; $i=0 if /^fi/' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

This script sets `$i` to `1` the first time it encounters a line starting with `#if ! shopt -oq posix;`. It sets it back to `0` if it encounters a line starting with `fi` (not `#fi`, because the substitution operator will have uncommented it at this point). Then, if `$i` is `1`, it removes comments from the start of the line.

#### Notes

- This will fail if you have more than one lines starting with `#if ! shopt -oq posix;`
- It will fail if you have a space after the `#`.

---

A much better approach would be to edit your file so that the relevant section is clearly delimited using something else. For example, `XXXstart` and `XXXend`:

Then, you can make a more general approach:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
# XXXstart
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi
#XXXend
```

Now, use this script on the file:

```
 perl -i -pe '$i=0 if /XXXend/; s/^\s*#*// if $i==1; $i=1 if /XXXstart/; ' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

---

Finally, don't do this. Don't mess with `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Just add these lines to *your* `~/.bashrc` file and avoid changing `/etc/bash.bashrc`. First because it is cleaner and safer and second because any changes you make to the file in `/etc` will be overwritten by the next update.

Comment: i like the idea of search for the first #if and starting to uncomment until the first #fi. i also understand the issues that can come from editing this file if an update will come in a later point. the reason behind my question is that i have to customize a clean cd installation with bsh script and this should be done also during deployment customization.

Comment: @AsafMagen a much cleaner way would be to save all this in a second file and source that from `.bashrc`. Up to you though.

Answer (score 0):

1. why not have a temporary file that you just concat to  `/etc/bash.bashrc` ?

   ```
   cat /tmp/posix-opt.txt >> /etc/bash.bashrc
   ```

(this will add /tmp/posix-opt.txt (which contains uncommented line) to /etc/bash.bashrc )

2. If not possible

   ```
   n=$(grep -n 'shopt -oq posix' /etc/bash.bashrc)
   sed -i -e "$n,$(($n + 7))s/^#//" /etc/bash.bashrc
   ```

this is the same as in vi, you just need the grep to get line number.

notice however, that should there be 2 lines containing "shopt -oq posix" the script will break.

Comment: you mean like a patch file to append to the original file?

Comment: yes just prepare the file once, then run `cat /tmp/posix-opt.txt >> /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: there will be duplicate line of code this way.

Comment: ?? in /tmp/posix-opt.txt you have uncommented line, while in /etc/bash.bashrc you have commented one.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what line in the file your block starts at (e.g, line 30), you can do it with

```
sed '31,+6s/^.//' </etc/bash.bashrc >/etc/bash.bashrc-uncommented
```

Then check your new file `bash.bashrc-uncommented` to make sure it's right before copying

```
mv /etc/bash.bashrc-uncommented /etc/bash.bashrc
```

---

What the `sed` statement is doing is looking for line 31 (the line after your block starts) and applying a regular expression to those 6 lines you asked for.

For each line, the regular expression looks for the beginning of the line `^` and the following character `.`, and replaces it with nothing (i.e., deletes it).

The `</etc/...` and `>/etc/...`  are telling `sed` where to find your file and where to send the result of the command.

Answer (score 0):

This proposed solution i came up that need some preparation but it's fine with me.

---

First i copied the source file to a temp folder

```
cp /etc/bash.bashrc /var/ldt/bash.bashrc_modifed
```

Then i edit only what i needed in /var/ldt/bash.bashrc_modifed.

Created the patch by running:

```
diff -u /etc/bash.bashrc /var/ldt/bash.bashrc_modifed > /var/ldt/bash.bashrc_patch
```

Now i can apply the change only to what i exactly want.

```
patch /etc/bash.bashrc < /var/ldt/bash.bashrc_patch
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with awk:

```
awk '/shopt -oq posix/ { sub("#","",$0); print; for(n=0; n<=6; n++) { getline ; sub("#","",$0); print} }1' </etc/bash.bashrc >NEWFILE
```

Then rename NEWFILE to /etc/bash.bashrc or whatever.